# In lapply(list(...), ._java_valid_object) : NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, coercion

```
a[1]
[1] "AA"
> rhive.query("select count( uniquecarrier)  from f08 where uniquecarrier= '",a[1] ," ' ")
Error: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 40000, cause: FAILED: ParseException line 1:61 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in expression specification
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lapply(list(...), ._java_valid_object) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lapply(list(...), ._java_valid_object) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I want to supply value vector value to rhive, but when I fire the above query it displays an error.

Comment: > sapply(dat2,mode)
     date     total 
"numeric" "numeric"

Comment: dat2<-data.frame(date=paste(wn08$year,wn08$month,wn08$dayofmonth,sep="/"),total=wn08$total) ...i m doing timeseries analysis..i have data about 365 days and i wnad to draw a timeseirs plot per month

Answer (score 1):

You are providing the query as separate arguments to `rhive.query`, which doesn't work (the command needs to be the [first argument](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RHive/docs/rhive.query)). You need to `paste0` them together first:

```
cmd <- paste0("select count( uniquecarrier)  from f08 where uniquecarrier= '", a[1] , "'")
cmd
# [1] "select count( uniquecarrier)  from f08 where uniquecarrier= 'AA'"

rhive.query(cmd)
```